# List to Dictionary in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary, identity-column

I have a column which has values stored as list. The column looks like:

```
[{'key': 'firebase_screen_class', 'value': 'MainViewController'},
 {'key': 'firebase_event_origin', 'value': 'auto'},
 {'key': 'firebase_screen_id', 'value': '81265142482196321'},
 {'key': 'engagement_time_msec', 'value': '3374'}]
```

I want to convert this into a column which looks like:

```
{'firebase_screen_class': 'MainViewController',
 'firebase_event_origin': 'auto',
 'firebase_screen_id': '81265142482196321',
 'engagement_time_msec': '3374'}
```

Comment: Hint: for each key its value is the key for you and for the value its key is the value for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list = [{'key': 'firebase_screen_class', 'value': 'MainViewController'},
        {'key': 'firebase_event_origin', 'value': 'auto'},
        {'key': 'firebase_screen_id', 'value': '81265142482196321'},
        {'key': 'engagement_time_msec', 'value': '3374'}]

result = dict()

for d in list:
     result[d['key']] = d['value']
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a dictionary comprehension:

```
{d['key']:d['value'] for d in col}
```

where `col` is your original column.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply do it using for loop:

```
l1 = [{'key': 'firebase_screen_class', 'value': 'MainViewController'},
     {'key': 'firebase_event_origin', 'value': 'auto'},
     {'key': 'firebase_screen_id', 'value': '81265142482196321'},
     {'key': 'engagement_time_msec', 'value': '3374'}]
final_dict = {}
for d1 in l1:
    final_dict[d1['key']] = d1['value']

print final_dict
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def dd(arr):
    di = {}
    for j in arr:
        di[j['key']] = j['value']
    return di

df['new_cil'] = df['col'].map(dd)
```